# How to view differences of image in git?

Tags: redmine

I use Redmine for my git repository.

I can view differences of text file just by clicking view differences.

But when I'm viewing differences of an image, nothing appeared on the screen.

Is there anyway to view the changes of image in redmine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git can only track differences for text files, not binary files.
So it will store different versions, but is unable to actually show the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Clone it to GitHub. They've got a feature to diff images online.